# Change properties of UIView created in for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I have added a few UIViews to my main view, one next to the other, programatically, like so:

```
//global variable
var lastLine: UIView!

//inside a function
for(var line = 0; line <= numberOfLines; line++){

        lastLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: lengthOfSpace + lengthOfLine * CGFloat(line) + lengthOfSpace * CGFloat(line), y: 8 * view.frame.height/10, width: lengthOfLine, height: 7))
        lastLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        lastLine.layer.cornerRadius = lastLine.frame.height/4
        view.addSubview(lastLine)

}
```

Now I would like to change the color of the last line I've created, so I did this:

```
        lastLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

But none of the lines change color as long as I attempt to change it from outside their for loop. Why does that happen? Is there any way I can change the line's color?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, that's odd - because it works for me.  I put your code in a function, and if I set the backgroundColor within the loop, then every line changes, and if I put it outside the loop, only the last one changes.

Silly question, but you don't specify the size of these lines - is there any chance the last line is drawn off screen, so that you don't see it?

Comment: It's always the silly things that get me! Indeed, the for loop was wrong, should have been < instead of <=, so there was an extra line I wasn't seeing!

Answer (score 1):

The issue probably revolves around how things are declared (a single view) versus how they are created (a potential array of views). Why not use the tag property of UIView to manipulate the specific view you want to change?

Let's say you have 5 lines/views and wish to manipulate line 3.

Code to create 5 views:

```
var numberOfLines:Int = 0

for line in 1...numberOfLines {
    let newView = UIView()
    // code to create and position UIView
    newView.tag = line
    view.addSubview(newView)
}
```

Code to manipulate the third line/view:

```
func alterLine(_ lineNumber:Int) {
    for view in view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if view.tag = lineNumber {
            // change view code
        }
    }
}
```

Since your working with UIViews, you need to beware that **any** view may have it's tag property set to this line number, even a UISlider! To get around this, you could subclass UIView and LineView, and alterLine() would be:

```
func alterLine(_ lineNumber:Int) {
    for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let lineView = view as? LineView {
            if lineView.tag = lineNumber {
                //change LineView code
            }
        }
    }
}
```